# Convention for public facing site's dev server

Tags: web, standards

I come from an enterprise environment where I primarily work on internal web applications. I'm interested in doing some web development on the side, but I have a few questions regarding how things are typically done outside an enterprise.

At work, we usually develop in three different environments; Development, Test, and Production. Standard naming convention is `<app name>-dev.<internal site>.com`, `<app name>-test.<internal site>.com`, `<app name>.<internal site>.com`. Since the web sites are internal to our VPN, there is no big deal if a user stumbles upon the dev or test sites. On the other hand, if I ran into say, the stack overflow development page, I would see that as a possible security risk.

I would imagine a site like stack overflow would have a development site, and that it would be impossible for me to navigate to. There must be some way to access it though, for say, testers.

**What are common ways to hide development sites from the public with exclusions for some people?**

The only method I can think of is to host the non production sites on a VPN or something, but all that setup seems almost excessive for a smaller business. I am not looking for answers like "login screen".

Comment: one solution I have used is a "magic cookie" that unless is present simply blocks or redirects the user. when registering a tester that cookie can get dropped (though does need a login). Other tricks include using hosts file to create DNS entries or require use of a specific proxy

Answer (score 0):

As far as naming conventions, they're not super-standardized and it varies on the framework used.
(Ex. in Rails you may have 'production', 'test', 'development')

Most of the time for development (and test) you don't need (or want) a publicly accessible web server.  Just run it on a your own internal network.  However you may need public access if your site needs things like webhooks called from other public sites (such as Salesforce), mobile devices outside a VPN etc.  You can probably do most of your work internally and deploy to a public site for dev for those times you need it.